# Spark scala how to count values in rows

Tags: scala, multidimensional-array, apache-spark, row

I am new to both Spark and Scala...and I have to read a data file and count the value that are contained in both columns and rows. The data set is structured like this:

```
0 0 2
0 2 2
0 2 0
2 0 0
0 0 0
0 1 0
```

In order to count the number of "2" in each column:

I imported the file:

```
val ip = sc.textFile("/home/../data-scala.txt")
```

I created an array to save my results

```
var ArrayCol = Array.ofDim[Long](3)

val cols = ip.map(line => line.split(" "))

for (i <- 0 to 2) {
    ArrayCol(i) = cols.map(col => col(i)).filter(_.contains("2")).count()
}
```

and I counted the number of "2" contained in each column.

Now I would like to do the same for each row. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cols.map(r => r.count(_ == "2"))
```

Or shell example:

```
scala> val cols = sc.parallelize(List("0 1 2", "2 0 2")).map(_.split(" "))
scala> cols.map(_.count(_ == "2")).collect()

res1: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok thank you

`cols.map(r => r.count(_ == "2"))`

works fine to count how many "2" there are in each row.

How would you do to count how many "2" there are in each column?
I think there is a more clear solution than mine.

Thanks.